# How to check harddisk maximum temperature throughout lifespan?

Tags: hard-disk, temperature, sensors

How to check harddisk maximum temperature throughout its lifespan in Linux?

In the Windows software [Hard Disk Sentinel](https://www.hdsentinel.com/), we can check the Maximum Temperature (during entire lifespan):

> The software displays the current hard disk temperature and logs maximum and average HDD temperatures.

This value is available even if a harddisk is connected to a PC for its first time. So I believe this is recorded in the sensor of the harddisk itself, instead of logging in the PC. Which software / commands could be used to check this value in Linux?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`smartctl` will show you the min/max temperature of a disk:

> tempminmax  - Raw Attribute is the disk temperature in Celsius.  Info
> about Min/Max temperature is printed if available.  This is the
> default for Attributes 190 and 194.  The recording interval
> (lifetime, last power cycle, last soft reset) of the min/max values is device specific.

---

Example:

```
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   060   060   ---    Old_age   Always       -       40 (Min/Max 10/60)
```

In this case 10°C is the minimum and 60°C is the maximum temperature the device experienced.

Comment: In my case (of another harddisk), I do not have the brackets (Min/Max) at the end. But there are VALUE = 106 and WORST = 091 in the columns. What do they mean?

Comment: I supposed WORST mean the maximum temperature during lifespan. However in another harddisk, it reads VALUE = 075, WORST = 075, RAW_VALUE = 25 (Min/Max 7/53).

Comment: From `man smartctl`: Each Attribute also has a "Worst" value shown under the heading "WORST".  This is the smallest (closest to failure) value that the disk has recorded at any time during its lifetime when SMART
              was enabled.  [Note however that some vendors firmware may actually increase the "Worst" value for some "rate-type" Attributes.]

Comment: @midnite Using `smartctl -l scttemp <device>` might give you output that's easier to consume.

Comment: @AndyDalton - Yeah this is great indeed.